# how best to compress aws images

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I check my home page with google page speed test I get notice to compress my images:
Compressing https://d1bng4142lcup0.cloudfront.net/…5c0-9e29-42af-ba42-b0ae59ef2809horse.JPG could save 51KiB (55% reduction).

I have rails 4.2 on heroku using jquery file uploader and aws-sdk to upload to s3 via js.  I then serve s3 image files via cloudfront.

In the js uploader I set the quality to .75 and size to around 500 px wide.  I serve one file to all devices (bootstrap responsive class displays it nicely).  I used this technique to upload https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails which uses https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I have gzip = true in my production.rb and I have compression turned on on cloudfront.

When looking at chrome developer tool under networking I see many things are content-encoding = gzip such as js files, but my png and jpg are not.  They do have content lengths however.

How do I compress my files automatically moving forward to speed up my site and satisfy the page speed tool?  How do I optimize existing images on s3 to be compressed?  In other words, do I need to do more during initial upload or can I do some compression on the aws side?

Comment: Do you need to compress only existed or new files too?

Comment: both existing and new